# Google Apps Script, copy formatting - still not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I still cannot get this right

my code.gs is  -

```
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];

var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dBaptSo-zR4BF8FWaw6YtARbzVMRqkpOokCE_UQvT80/edit#gid=1268776645");

sheet.copyTo(Event Calendar!A1:AH1400);
```

I have copied a sheet that is an active sheet that all sales works on to add events - this sheet has colours - i used importrange to import that sheet into a viewable only sheet but it only imported the data not the formatting with the colours - i have read many pages and comments and i used the code above - this is the import range i have used - =importRange("SPREADSHEET_URL","Event Calendar!A1:AH1400") -

Direct link to the document for the events that sales will be editing on is - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dBaptSo-zR4BF8FWaw6YtARbzVMRqkpOokCE_UQvT80/edit#gid=1268776645 - the sheet is importranged to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/168Yd8AcS__FY0WiF-1RQKJBvVDvs4vXpgZPL3QCnHOw/edit#gid=1133391220 -

it is the events tab and it is for viewing only - the importrange only copied data i need it to copy the formatting -

is still giving me the same error Missing ) after argument list. (line 7, file "Code")

Comment: It is still giving me the same error  Missing ) after argument list. (line 7, file "Code")

Comment: Use `getValues()` and `setValues()`. [Edit] your question to add additional information. Comments will be deleted. `copyTo` can't be used between  spreadsheets(only between sheets). The correct syntax is `sheet.copyTo(source.getRange("'Event Calendar'!A1:AH1400"));`(which will give you a error, if Event Calendar is not a sheet in source)

Comment: @Maria Don't share your spreadsheet IDs on public forums. You wouldn't put your cell phone number or home address on here would you?

Answer (score 0):

There are two code lines with syntax errors

On `var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dBaptSo-zR4BF8FWaw6YtARbzVMRqkpOokCE_UQvT80/edit#gid=1268776645");` the argument should be a spreadsheet id but the current argument includes extra characters.

Try `var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dBaptSo-zR4BF8FWaw6YtARbzVMRqkpOokCE_UQvT80");` For further details checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid

On `sheet.copyTo(Event Calendar!A1:AH1400);` the argument should be an spreadsheet object. For further details checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)

Comment: I still just cannot seem to get it right - I have updated my question